# What about throwing out 2/3rds of a data set?

Tags: dataset, model-selection

I have a data set of presidential election results for the past 33 elections. I threw out everything pre 1972, however, because of the structural changes that occurred through the decades, and because I am assuming a degree of auto-correlation in the data, so I want to get rid of previous trends that are not material contemporarily.

With the entire data set, I could not get any models with a decent R-squared, the highest was .068, and P value was 15 percent. However, after dropping all of the data up to the year 1972, I was able to fit a different model that had a P value of .028 and also had an R-squared of .45. The current data set consists of 10 points. If I add in 2 more data points, p value is still small, and the R-squared drops to about 30.

Is it okay that I dropped this data?

Comment: What are you modelling ie what is the explanatory variable?  It makes a difference if there are good a priori reasons for using 1972 as the beginning of your series.  I would need to be convinced that this is the right moment for identifying significant structural change - it depends on "change in what?"

Comment: federally, poll taxes were abolished in 65, for states in 66 and in 72, age restrictions were dropped to 18 nationally. I assume that this impacted the makeup of voters and would have also changed overall voter preferences such that we wouldn't expect particular variables to have the same impact. In addition we had a 4 term president, and odd economic events happening during WWI/WWII which are impossible today due to structural legislative changes.

this could be a reason that the rsquared is now so high when fitted to this small data set. Im just worried about overfitting and sought opinions.

Answer (score 8):

The problem isn't *specifically* dropping data - that just changes what you are modeling. However, two problems may arise:

1. "Fishing". The ideal is to come up with an hypothesis a priori and then test it and then stop. This ideal is often violated. If you have some good *substantive* reason for violating it, then you may get away with it.
2. Overfitting. With only 10 points, you should (by the usual rule of thumb) have only one independent variable. This is, in my view, a harder problem to get around.

Comment: 1.please see my comment above for justification of this decision. 
2.I only have one variable, which is an interaction term, G:Z, so this satisfies your criteria of only 1 independent variable right? So, given that I only have one term, is it good that i have found such a high R squared and low p value? 
3.Also, someone suggested that I create a dummy variable essentially switching the data between all-data/post-72 data. If you think that is a superior approach, could you give me guidance as to how I might make that dummy variable if my model is currently VP~G:Z.

Comment: 1. Well, it's very rare that you want an interaction term without the main effects. 2. In general, high $R^2$ is good. 3. How to create a dummy variable depends on your software.